# i want to Show a "Thanks for voting" message after a user votes for all the positions and then it will show that message

Tags: python, html, django, django-templates

after a user votes for all the available positions then its just redirecting to the Position page , and i want to show a Message or a alert that "the user has voted for all the positions".
help me out how to do that?

**view.py:**

```
def home(request):
    return render(request, 'home.html')

def registration(request):
    if request.method == "POST":
       form = RegistrationForm(request.POST, request.FILES)
    
    if form.is_valid():
        cd = form.cleaned_data
     
        if cd['password'] == cd['confirm_password']:
            obj = form.save(commit=False)
            obj.set_password(obj.password)
            obj.save()
            
            messages.success(request, 'You have been registered.')
            return redirect('home')
        else:
            return render(request, "registration.html", {'form':form,'note':'password must match'})
else:
    form = RegistrationForm()

return render(request, "registration.html", {'form':form})


def login(request):
   if request.method == "POST":
    usern = request.POST.get('username')
    passw = request.POST.get('password')
    user = authenticate(request, username=usern, password=passw)
    if user is not None:
        dj_login(request, user)
        return redirect('dashboard')
    else:
        messages.success(request, 'Invalid username or password!')
        return render(request, "login.html")
   else:
    return render(request, "login.html")      


@login_required
 def candidate(request, pos):
     obj = get_object_or_404(Position, pk = pos)

if request.method == "POST":
    temp = ControlVote.objects.get_or_create(user=request.user, position=obj)[0]
    
    if temp.status == False:
        temp2 = Candidate.objects.get(pk=request.POST.get(obj.title))
        temp2.total_vote += 1
        temp2.save()
        temp.status = True
        temp.save()
        return HttpResponseRedirect('/position/')
        

    else:
        messages.success(request, 'Thanks for voting, you have already been voted this position.')
        return render(request, 'candidate.html', {'obj':obj})

   else:
        return render(request, 'candidate.html', {'obj':obj})
```

**HTML:**
this is my HTML HOME Template

```
   {% load static %}
  <!doctype html>
  <html lang="en">
  <head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.4.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-Vkoo8x4CGsO3+Hhxv8T/Q5PaXtkKtu6ug5TOeNV6gBiFeWPGFN9MuhOf23Q9Ifjh" crossorigin="anonymous">

 <title>{% block title %}{% endblock %}</title>
 </head>
 <body>
 <nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg navbar-light bg-warning">

 <a class="navbar-brand" href="{% url 'home' %}">University Students Association Voting System</a>
 <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbarNavAltMarkup" aria-controls="navbarNavAltMarkup" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
 <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
 </button>

 <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarNavAltMarkup">
   <div class="navbar-nav ml-auto ">
   {% if request.user.is_authenticated %}
      <a class="nav-item nav-link" href="{% url 'dashboard' %}">Dashboard</a>
      <a class="nav-item nav-link" href="{% url 'editprofile' %}">Edit Profile</a>
      <a class="nav-item nav-link" href="{% url 'changepass' %}">Change Password</a>
      <a class="nav-item nav-link" href="{% url 'logout' %}">Logout</a>
    {% else %}
      <a class="nav-item nav-link" href="{% url 'login' %}"></i>Login</a><br>
       <a class="nav-item nav-link" href="{% url 'registration' %}">Register</a>
    {% endif %}
    
    {% block branding %}
        <h1 id="University Student Association Voting System">
        <a href="{% url 'admin:index' %}"></a></h1>
    {% endblock %}

  </div>
  </div>
  </nav>
  <br>
  <div class="container">   
  {% block content %}
       
  {% endblock %}
  </div>
  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.4.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-J6qa4849blE2+poT4WnyKhv5vZF5SrPo0iEjwBvKU7imGFAV0wwj1yYfoRSJoZ+n" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
  <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/popper.js@1.16.0/dist/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-Q6E9RHvbIyZFJoft+2mJbHaEWldlvI9IOYy5n3zV9zzTtmI3UksdQRVvoxMfooAo" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
  <script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.4.1/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-wfSDF2E50Y2D1uUdj0O3uMBJnjuUD4Ih7YwaYd1iqfktj0Uod8GCExl3Og8ifwB6" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.5.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.4.1/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

  </body>
  </html>
```

**Position Html Template :** this is the position template .

```
{% extends "base.html" %}
{% block title %}Position{% endblock %}
{% block content %}

<h2 style="color:#05386B;">Available Position For Vote </h2><hr><br> &nbsp;
<ul>
{% for i in obj %}
   <li><b><a href="{% url 'candidate' i.id %}" style="color:blue;">{{i.title}}</a></b></li><br>
{% empty %}
  <p>No Positions Available</p>
{% endfor %}
</ul>
```

**Module.py**

```
from django.db import models
from django.contrib.auth.models import User
from django.db.models.signals import post_save
from django.dispatch import receiver


class Position(models.Model):
     title = models.CharField(max_length=50, unique=True)

def __str__(self):
    return self.title


class Candidate(models.Model):
     name = models.CharField(max_length=50)
total_vote = models.IntegerField(default=0, editable=False)
position = models.ForeignKey(Position, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
image = models.ImageField(verbose_name="Candidate Pic", 
  upload_to='images/')

party = models.CharField(max_length=50, blank=True)
course = models.CharField(max_length=50, blank=True)
about = models.CharField(max_length=1000, blank=True)
year = models.CharField(max_length=1000, blank=True)
manifesto = models.TextField(max_length=1000, blank=True)
achievements = models.CharField(max_length=1000, blank=True)
def __str__(self):
    return "{} - {}".format(self.name, self.position.title)


class ControlVote(models.Model):
user = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
position = models.ForeignKey(Position, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
status = models.BooleanField(default=False)

def __str__(self):
    return "{} - {} - {}".format(self.user, self.position, self.status)
```

**Forms.py:**

```
from django import forms
from django.forms import ModelForm
from django.contrib.auth.models import User
from django.contrib.auth import get_user_model


class RegistrationForm(forms.ModelForm):
     confirm_password = forms.CharField(max_length=100, 
      widget=forms.PasswordInput)


class Meta:
    model = User
    fields = ['username', 'first_name', 'last_name', 'email', 'password']
    widgets = {
        'password': forms.PasswordInput
    }


class ChangeForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
         model = User
    fields = ['username', 'first_name', 'last_name', 'email']
```

**urls.py**

```
from django.contrib import admin
from django.urls import path
from voting import views
from django.shortcuts import render
from django import forms
from django.conf import settings
from django.conf.urls.static import static


urlpatterns = [
path('admin/', admin.site.urls),
path('', views.home, name='home'),
path('home/', views.home, name='home'),
path('registration/', views.registration, name='registration'),
path('dashboard/', views.dashboard, name='dashboard'),
path('editprofile/', views.editprofile, name='editprofile'),
path('login/', views.login, name='login'),
path('logout/', views.logout, name='logout'),
path('changepass/', views.changepass, name='changepass'),
path('position/', views.position, name='position'),
path('result/', views.result, name='result'),
path('candidate/detail/<int:id>/', views.candidate_detail, name='detail'),
path('candidate/<int:pos>/', views.candidate, name='candidate'),
] + static(settings.MEDIA_URL, document_root=settings.MEDIA_ROOT) 

admin.site.site_header = "University Students Association Voting System"
admin.site.index_title = "Welcome to University Students Association Voting 
System admin panel"
admin.site.site_title = "OVS"
```

Comment: As a start your indentations are probably incorrect, see for example the function `def candidate(request, pos):` `if request.method == "POST":` should be part of this function, so must be indented.

Comment: its already there

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I understand you build from an existing app.

In order to check if a user has already voted for a candidate I would change the following:
`views.py`: compare the sets of all positions `set(Position.objects.all())` with the set of positions where the user has already voted `set(v.position for v in ControlVote.objects.filter(user=request.user))`. Take the difference of the two sets to get the remaining list of positions where a vote is still required and render this list.

```
@login_required
def positionView(request):
    positions = set(Position.objects.all())
    voted_positions = set(v.position for v in ControlVote.objects.filter(user=request.user))
    not_voted_positions = list(positions - voted_positions)
    return render(request, "poll/position.html", {'positions':not_voted_positions})
```

and in the template `positions.html`, if the list of positions is empty change the message to `Thank you {{ user.first_name }} {{ user.last_name }}. You have voted for all candidates`

```
{% extends "poll/base.html" %}

{% block title %}{% endblock %}

{% block content %}
  <h2>Available Position For Vote</h2>
  <ul>
    {% for position in positions %}
      <li><a href="{% url 'candidate' position.id %}">{{position.title}}</a></li>
    {% empty %}
      <p>Thank you {{ user.first_name }} {{ user.last_name }}. You have voted for all candidates</p>
    {% endfor %}
  </ul>
{% endblock %}
```

note I have changed some of names of the variables to make the program better readable.

Comment: Ok sir . I added the models, forms and urls files there. i dont have any syntax error or anything .i just want to add an alert after a user votes for all the position ,thats what my problem is. i hope you will help me :-)

Comment: If you have the code on github that would be a great help. Then I can just clone the repository and start troubleshooting.

Comment: I see you are building from an existing app, which is running just fine after cloning from github. Will have a look at it today.

Comment: yes sir its working fine i just want to add a alert or message as i mentioned above .

Comment: If you do not want to render to the `position.html` just do the check and redirect to another page

Comment: This answer is a bit too broad for SO. You would have to go to buildfaast.com or something similar for this.

Comment: my problem was "if a user votes for all the available positions one by one then after they votes for the last position i want to show a alert or message" your code was looking fine but its not working with the problem sir . @BrunoVermeulen

Comment: May I suggest my code is even working better! It only provides the list of positions the user has not yet voted for. If the user has voted for all positions then he/ she will be informed as such. If you want him to get a message in the event the list of `not_voted_positions` is empty, check this in `positionView` and redirect to whatever view you want.

Comment: can you help me ? how can a voter check whom he voted ? can we display its voted candidate list ?

Comment: Probably easiest will be to add a model class to capture `Candidate` and `User` to store what a user has been voted. Will give you a solution when you give my kuddos for my previous answer.

Comment: Have a look at https://github.com/bvermeulen/ovs. You need to start with a clean table in the database for `poll_controlvote` as the model has been changed.

Comment: Please can you tick answered to my original answer, so I get my kudos. Thanks a lot!